# Python What is way of Writing a Variable output into a file if a function defined

Tags: python, python-3.5

How to write a variable data info a file in case function is defined.
While i'm trying below method but it just write few lines only:

Please let me know what mistake i'm doing here...

```
fileData = 'ldap_conn_logs'
def ChkCon():
    Flag    = False
    FlagTcp = False
    NewStr  = ''
    OutStr  = ''
    HOST    = ''
    MARKER  = '----------------'
    NEWLINE = '\n'
    with open('ldap_bind_netstat', 'r') as log:
        for line in log:
            if '| SUCCESS |' in line:
                if Flag:
                    return HOST
                    return MARKER
                    return NewStr
            if '| SUCCESS |' in line:
                Flag = False
                FlagTcp = True
                HOST = line.split()[0]
                NewStr = ''
            elif 'FAILED' in line:
                FlagTcp = False
            elif 'UNREACHABLE' in line:
                FlagTcp = False
            if FlagTcp and line.startswith('tcp'):
                NewStr += line
                if 'tsdj-lb-oidc01' not in line:
                    Flag = True
                OutStr = HOST + NEWLINE + MARKER + NEWLINE + NewStr
                fileWrite = open(fileData, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
                fileWrite.write(OutStr)
                fileWrite.close()
ChkCon()
```

Comment: What is `someOutput`? It's not defined anywhere

Comment: You are opening the file in "write" mode in the `for` loop, which will overwrite whatever text you have already written in the file in each iteration of the loop. Please use mode `a` instead as @Hans suggested.!

Comment: @Vinny .. i have edited the actual code tried, but while doing it it does not write the actual `OutStr ` data into file

Comment: @JayJoshi ..  mistakenly i kept `+w`.

Comment: @reculseSoul, did changing the mode solve the issue.?

Comment: @JayJoshi, no it did not Still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@reculseSoul, Use `str.format` method and close the `fileWrite.close()` outside the for loop. Please try below it should work.

```
def ChkCon():
    Flag    = False
    FlagTcp = False
    NewStr  = ''
    OutStr  = ''
    HOST    = ''
    MARKER  = '----------------'
    NEWLINE = '\n'
    fileData = 'ldap_conn_logs'
    with open('ldap_bind_netstat', 'r') as log:
        for line in log:
            if '| SUCCESS |' in line:
                if Flag:
                    return HOST
                    return MARKER
                    return NewStr
            if '| SUCCESS |' in line:
                Flag = False
                FlagTcp = True
                HOST = line.split()[0]
                NewStr = ''
            elif 'FAILED' in line:
                FlagTcp = False
            elif 'UNREACHABLE' in line:
                FlagTcp = False
            if FlagTcp and line.startswith('tcp'):
                NewStr += line
                if 'tsdj-lb-oidc01' not in line:
                    Flag = True
                OutStr = HOST + NEWLINE + MARKER + NEWLINE + NewStr
                fileWrite = open(fileData, 'w')
                fileWrite.write(OutStr)
                file.write('{0}'.format(OutStr))
        fileWrite.close()
        log.close()
ChkCon()
```

Answer (score 1):

As Vinny mentioned, this example is neither complete nor verifiable. My best guess is that you want to replace `mode='w+'` with `mode='a'`. You don't seem to be actually reading `fileData`, so don't bother with the `+`. Write mode overwrites your file every time you run through the loop.

Comment: Hans Musgrave, I have edited the real code tried , just to see what wrong i'm doing..